# How to ignore log property base on class type with Serilog

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, aop, serilog

I'm implement AOP using Serilog to log all method call and parameters value
Here is my code:

```
_logger.ForContext(targetType).Information("INVOKE {@guid} {@MethodName} with parameters {@arg}", guid, invocation.Method.Name, invocation.Arguments);
```

However, some parameter type cannot to be log as DataTable, DataSet, Image, byte[] ...
How can I ignore these type in Serilog?

Comment: Either filter them out of the arguments before passing the array or write custom Destructurer that can convert them to something that is meaningful to log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy solution is to tell Serilog upfront that types such as `DataSet`, `DataTable`, etc. should be destructured as scalar values. E.g.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Destructure.AsScalar(typeof(DataSet))
    .Destructure.AsScalar(typeof(DataTable))
    // ...
    .CreateLogger();
```

You can also use `.Destructure.ByTransforming` or `.Destructure.ByTransformingWhere`.

Another solution is to create a custom [destructuring policy](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data#customizing-the-stored-data) where you decide how to destructure different types:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Destructure.With<IgnoreSomeTypesDestructuringPolicy>()
    // ...
    .CreateLogger();

public class IgnoreSomeTypesDestructuringPolicy : IDestructuringPolicy
{
    public bool TryDestructure(object value, ILogEventPropertyValueFactory propertyValueFactory, out LogEventPropertyValue result)
    {
        if (value is DataTable || value is DataSet /* ... */)
        {
            result = new ScalarValue(value.ToString());
            return true;
        }

        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```